# Passing generated id from one page to another

Tags: javascript

I really really need your help pls. I have been battling with these for days and my project is stucked. Your help will really be appreciated.

I have 3 pages.

Page one receives my data, and html formatted version is created. it is a loop and it returns 10 posts.

```
===
```

page 2 is the html page that displays the 10 post

```
====
```

page 3. the posts at page 2 are just featured image and excerpt and title with url... to read full, click it and go to page 3 ...

Page 3 uses the unique id of each posts to display the full post:

my question: how do i pass each post id to page 3 for full content view.

i tried to store the id generated in page 1 to localstorage, but bcos its a loop ... ONLY THE LAST ONE IS STORED..
my code..

Page 1 - script page receives data

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");

function onDeviceReady(){

 var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed');
 ourRequest.onload = function() {
  if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
    var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
 createHTML(data);
    console.log(data);

     } else {
      console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
    }
  };

  ourRequest.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Connection error");
  };

  ourRequest.send();

}


Page 1 still: CreateHTMl create thru a loop

function createHTML(postsData) {
 var ourHTMLString = '';

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) 

  {


    var posturl = postsData.link   
    ourHTMLString +='<tr>';

    ourHTMLString += '<td>' + '<a href="loadpost.html" + rel="external" + " style="text-decoration:none ">'  + postsData[i].title.rendered + '</a>'+'</td>';
 ourHTMLString += '<td>' + '<a href="loadpost.html"><img width="100%" src ="' + postsData[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url + '"  />' + '</a>'+'</td>';
ourHTMLString += '<td>' + postsData[i].excerpt.rendered +  localStorage.setItem("postid",postsData[i].id)+'</td>';
//i tried to store each id in a localstorage but only the last one remains
ourHTMLString+= '</tr>';
 } portfolioPostsContainer.innerHTML = ourHTMLString;

}

page two uses this to display ourHTMLString

 <div id="portfolio-posts-container"></div>

page 3 Need each post id.

function onDeviceReady(){

   var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'+mypostid+'?_embed=true')
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      //  createHTML(data);  '+mypostid)
        console.log(data);

        var ourHTMLString = '';


Each post has its generated id from the api, how do i pass it to page 3 for displaying individual post
```

Comment: I think you should handle that in your backend with a proper API. Saving `id` in client side and using it in other pages is a very bad method and is a poor programming solution.

Comment: though it for mobile app.  how do i save it in client side... i created localstorage for it, but only the last generated post id got stored in localstorage...pls show me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm a little confused as re the overall structure of this system, you could pass the id as a query string parameter.

```
<a href="page3.html?id=123">View post 123</a>
```

This can be parsed using `location.search` within JavaScript:

```
var postMatch = /id=(\d+)/.exec(location.search);
if(postMatch) {
    var postId = postMatch[1];
    // Load post postId...
} else {
    // No post was passed
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. it means a lot to me thanks. checking it out

Comment: Thanks so much. This really did it for me. I am so grateful for your time.